# undefined error to template class function

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates

**I was trying implement an class template DoublyLinked list. I used to class here DoublyLinkde List and Double Node.  And Implemented here inserts() and Display Function.

Can anybody help me to successfully insert and display operation.**  For example i want to  insert data by using insert function and want to see it by using display function.

The below is the code: I write this code in final.cpp file

```
template <class ItemType> //Reminder this is a template class, implement the .cpp accordingly
class DoubleNode
{
public:
    DoubleNode();
    //default constructor, sets next_ and prev_ to nullptr
    DoubleNode(const ItemType &anItem, DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr = nullptr, DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr = nullptr); //Parameterized Constructor, sets item_ to anItem, next_ to nextNodePtr, prev_ to previousNodePtr

    void setItem(const ItemType &anItem)
    {

        item_=anItem;
    }

    void setPrevious(DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr)
    {
        next_= previousNodePtr;
    }


    void setNext(DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr)
    {
        prev_=nextNodePtr;

    }

    ItemType getItem() const
    {

        return item_;
    }

    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getNext() const
    {

        return next_;
    }

    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getPrevious() const
    {
        return prev_;

    }

private:
    ItemType item_;              //actual content of your node
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *next_; //pointer to the node that is after this node
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *prev_; //pointer to the node that is before this node
};



template <class ItemType>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    // DoublyLinkedList(); //default constructor, sets headPtr_ to null and itemCount_ to 0

    /*
        Copy constructor that will make an exact copy of the list parameter, aList.
        This will make a deep copy of the list in the given parameter.
        You must iterate through the callee list parameter and insert nodes from aList into the caller list (the current one that isn't the parameter)
    */
    // DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList &aList);

    // ~DoublyLinkedList(); //destructor that calls the clear function
    int getSize()
    {

        return itemCount_;

    } //return itemCount_

    /* *
        * Description: finds the node at parameter pos
        * Pre: pos is a valid place in the list, otherwise nullptr will be returned
        * Post: returns a pointer to the node at pos
    * */
    DoubleNode <ItemType> *getAtPos(const int &pos) const
    {
        DoubleNode<ItemType>* curPtr=headPtr_;
        for(int skip=1; skip<pos; skip++)
            curPtr=curPtr->getNext();
        return curPtr;
    }

    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getHeadPtr() const
    {

        return headPtr_;
    } //return *headPtr_

    /* *
        * Description: inserts parameter item in caller list at parameter position
            *IMPORTANT: Position 1 is the first position, not 0
        * Pre: position is a valid place within the list, otherwise false will be returned
        * Post: returns true if the item has been inserted in the caller list
        * Handles edge case of an invalid position parameter
        * Case: Inserting into head of the list
        * Case: Inserting into rear of the list
        * Case: Inserting into a position that is not an extremity
    * */

    bool inserts(const ItemType &item, const int &position = 1)
    {
        bool ableToInsert=(position>=1)&&(position<=itemCount_+1);
        if(ableToInsert)
        {
            DoubleNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr=new DoubleNode<ItemType>(item);
            if(position==1)
            {
                newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr_);
                headPtr_=newNodePtr;
            }
            else   if(position==2)
            {

                DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr=getAtPos(position-1);
                newNodePtr->setNext(prevPtr->getNext());
                prevPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);
            }

            else
            {
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* headPtr_=getHeadPtr();
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* node = new DoubleNode<ItemType>[1];
//      cout<<"test 31"<<endl;
                node->setItem(item);
                if(headPtr_ == nullptr)
                {
                    // cout<<"test 1"<<endl;
                    headPtr_ = node;
                    // cout<<"new node added(firstnode) !"<<endl;
                    return true;
                }
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* temp = headPtr_;
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* prev_;
                // cout<<"test 1 "<<temp->next_<<endl;
                while(temp->getNext() != nullptr)
                {
                    //cout<<"test NULL 1"<<endl;
                    prev_ = temp;
                    temp = temp->getNext();
                }
                temp->setNext(node);
                temp->setPrevious(prev_);
                //cout<<"new node added at back!"<<endl;
            }
            itemCount_++;
        }

        return ableToInsert;
    }

    /* *
        * Description: removes node at parameter position
            *IMPORTANT: Position 1 is the first position, not 0
        * Pre: position is a valid place within the list, otherwise false will be returned
        * Post: returns true if the item at position has been removed from the caller list
        * Handles edge case of invalid position parameter
        * Case: removing only node in list
        * Case: removing from the end
        * Case: removing from the beginning
        * Case: removing from a position that is not an extremity
    * */
    // bool remove(const int &position);

    // bool isEmpty() const; //returns true if itemCount_ is 0

    /* *
        * Description: removes all items from the caller list
        * Traverse through the linked list and delete each individual node
        * Post: no nodes remain in the list and itemCount_ is at 0
    * */
    // void clear();

    //Iteratively outputs the contents of the caller list on the console
    //Example "A B C D E"
    //Note how theres no space at the end
    void display() const
    {
//     cout<<"linked list is empty"<<endl;
        DoubleNode <ItemType>*headPtr_=getHeadPtr();
        if(headPtr_ == nullptr)
        {
            // cout<<"linked list is empty"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        // cout<<endl<<"----link list items------"<<endl;
        DoubleNode<ItemType>* temp = headPtr_;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            // cout<<temp->item_<<" ooo| ";
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }
        //  cout<<endl<<"--------------------------"<<endl;
    }

    //Iteratively outputs the contents of the caller list backwards on the console
    //Example if we had A B C D E we would instead display "E D C B A"
    //  void displayBackwards() const;

    // Reverses the list such that if my list was A B C D it will now be D C B A
    // Remember to change both previous and next pointers
    // Will be tested with both display and displayBackwards, make sure you have those working
    //  void invert();

private:
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *headPtr_; //points to the first item in the linked list
    int itemCount_;                 //lists how many items are currently in the list
};

int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList<int> dl;

    dl.inserts(4,3);
    dl.display();
}
```

Comment: Please break out the problematic parts and create a [mre]. Then describe the problem in detail. What is the result you expect and what does your implementation produce instead?

Comment: `DoubleNode` constructors aren't defined, just delcared. `setPrevious` sets the `next_` and `setNext` sets `prev_`.

Comment: @kiner_shah  could you please write down the code? cause i can't understand what you said

Comment: @MirRahat, `DoubleNode` constructors are just declared (they end with a semicolon `;`), where are their respective function bodies? And review your `setPrevious` and `setNext` functions.

Comment: @kiner_shah   could you please make me clear about setPrevious and setNext function? I mean what i have to do?

Comment: You are setting  `next_= previousNodePtr;` inside `setPrevious`. You should instead do: `prev_ = previousNodePtr;`. Same for `setNext`.

Comment: @kiner_shah  Update it by below, but code doesn't show any error also output though i called display function. PLease me how i would be able to insert data and display the data
https://justpaste.it/3jx8l

Comment: Please add the changes you have done in the post in a separate section, and highlight the issues you now face.

Comment: @kiner_shah  just setNext and setPrevious function.

Comment: What you need to do is to debug your code either using a debugger or placing print statements at different places.

Comment: @kiner_shah   i did but facing problem about  temp->next   convert it using setText or getText function.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the lines and blocks of code with the comment `// CHANGE HERE`.

Summary of changes:

1. Added definitions for constructor of `DoubleNode`.
2. Changed `setPrevious` and `setNext` so that it correctly sets `next_` and `prev_`.
3. Added a constructor for `DoublyLinkedList` and an empty destructor (you can fill it later).
4. Changed logic of `inserts`.
5. Changed `display` function a bit.
6. Changed `main` function. Note that `inserts` returns a `bool` but you weren't checking the return value.

P. S. Go through this modified code very carefully and try to understand what changes were done. Also, when something doesn't work, you must review the logic, debug the code using a debugger or simple print statements and fix any bugs.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class ItemType> //Reminder this is a template class, implement the .cpp accordingly
class DoubleNode
{
public:
    //default constructor, sets next_ and prev_ to nullptr
    // CHANGE HERE
    DoubleNode() : next_(nullptr), prev_(nullptr)
    {
    }
    
    //Parameterized Constructor, sets item_ to anItem, next_ to nextNodePtr, prev_ to previousNodePtr
    // CHANGE HERE
    DoubleNode(const ItemType &anItem, DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr = nullptr, DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr = nullptr)
    : next_(nextNodePtr), prev_(previousNodePtr), item_(anItem)
    {
    }

    void setItem(const ItemType &anItem)
    {

        item_=anItem;
    }

    void setPrevious(DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr)
    {
        // CHANGE HERE
        prev_ = previousNodePtr;
    }


    void setNext(DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr)
    {
        // CHANGE HERE
        next_ = nextNodePtr;

    }

    ItemType getItem() const
    {

        return item_;
    }

    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getNext() const
    {

        return next_;
    }

    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getPrevious() const
    {
        return prev_;

    }

private:
    ItemType item_;              //actual content of your node
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *next_; //pointer to the node that is after this node
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *prev_; //pointer to the node that is before this node
};



template <class ItemType>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    //default constructor, sets headPtr_ to null and itemCount_ to 0
    // CHANGE HERE
    DoublyLinkedList() : headPtr_(nullptr), itemCount_(0)
    {    
    }

    /*
        Copy constructor that will make an exact copy of the list parameter, aList.
        This will make a deep copy of the list in the given parameter.
        You must iterate through the callee list parameter and insert nodes from aList into the caller list (the current one that isn't the parameter)
    */
    // DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList &aList);

    //destructor that calls the clear function
    // CHANGE HERE
    ~DoublyLinkedList()
    {
    }
    
    int getSize()
    {
        return itemCount_;
    }

    /* *
        * Description: finds the node at parameter pos
        * Pre: pos is a valid place in the list, otherwise nullptr will be returned
        * Post: returns a pointer to the node at pos
    * */
    DoubleNode <ItemType> *getAtPos(const int &pos) const
    {
        DoubleNode<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr_;
        for (int skip = 1; curPtr != nullptr && skip < pos; skip++)
            curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
        return curPtr;
    }

    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getHeadPtr() const
    {
        return headPtr_;
    }

    /* *
        * Description: inserts parameter item in caller list at parameter position
            *IMPORTANT: Position 1 is the first position, not 0
        * Pre: position is a valid place within the list, otherwise false will be returned
        * Post: returns true if the item has been inserted in the caller list
        * Handles edge case of an invalid position parameter
        * Case: Inserting into head of the list
        * Case: Inserting into rear of the list
        * Case: Inserting into a position that is not an extremity
    * */

    bool inserts(const ItemType &item, const int &position = 1)
    {
        bool ableToInsert = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount_ + 1);
        if (ableToInsert)
        {
            DoubleNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new DoubleNode<ItemType>(item);
            if (position == 1)
            {
                //newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr_);    // CHANGE HERE
                headPtr_ = newNodePtr;
            }
            else    // CHANGE HERE
            {
                if (headPtr_ == nullptr)
                {
                    std::cout << "ERROR: cannot insert at position " << position << ", head is nullptr\n";
                    return false;
                }
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr = getAtPos(position - 1);
                // CHANGE HERE
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevNextPtr = prevPtr->getNext();
                prevPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);
                newNodePtr->setPrevious(prevPtr);
                newNodePtr->setNext(prevNextPtr);
                if (prevNextPtr)
                    prevNextPtr->setPrevious(newNodePtr);
            }

            // CHANGE HERE
            /*else
            {
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* headPtr_ = getHeadPtr();
                // CHANGE HERE
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* node = new DoubleNode<ItemType>(item);
                // CHANGE HERE
                if (headPtr_ == nullptr)
                {
                    std::cout << "ERROR: cannot insert at position " << position << ", head is nullptr\n";
                    return false;
                }
                
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevNode = getAtPos(position - 1);
                
                if(headPtr_ == nullptr)
                {
                    // cout<<"test 1"<<endl;
                    headPtr_ = node;
                    // cout<<"new node added(firstnode) !"<<endl;
                    return true;
                }
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* temp = headPtr_;
                DoubleNode<ItemType>* prev_;
                // cout<<"test 1 "<<temp->next_<<endl;
                while(temp->getNext() != nullptr)
                {
                    //cout<<"test NULL 1"<<endl;
                    prev_ = temp;
                    temp = temp->getNext();
                }
                temp->setNext(node);
                temp->setPrevious(prev_);
                //cout<<"new node added at back!"<<endl;
            }*/
            itemCount_++;
        }
        
        return ableToInsert;
    }

    /* *
        * Description: removes node at parameter position
            *IMPORTANT: Position 1 is the first position, not 0
        * Pre: position is a valid place within the list, otherwise false will be returned
        * Post: returns true if the item at position has been removed from the caller list
        * Handles edge case of invalid position parameter
        * Case: removing only node in list
        * Case: removing from the end
        * Case: removing from the beginning
        * Case: removing from a position that is not an extremity
    * */
    // bool remove(const int &position);

    // bool isEmpty() const; //returns true if itemCount_ is 0

    /* *
        * Description: removes all items from the caller list
        * Traverse through the linked list and delete each individual node
        * Post: no nodes remain in the list and itemCount_ is at 0
    * */
    // void clear();

    //Iteratively outputs the contents of the caller list on the console
    //Example "A B C D E"
    //Note how theres no space at the end
    // CHANGE HERE
    void display() const
    {
//     cout<<"linked list is empty"<<endl;
        DoubleNode <ItemType>*headPtr_=getHeadPtr();
        if(headPtr_ == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "linked list is empty" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        // cout<<endl<<"----link list items------"<<endl;
        DoubleNode<ItemType>* temp = headPtr_;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << temp->getItem() << " | ";
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

    //Iteratively outputs the contents of the caller list backwards on the console
    //Example if we had A B C D E we would instead display "E D C B A"
    //  void displayBackwards() const;

    // Reverses the list such that if my list was A B C D it will now be D C B A
    // Remember to change both previous and next pointers
    // Will be tested with both display and displayBackwards, make sure you have those working
    //  void invert();

private:
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *headPtr_; //points to the first item in the linked list
    int itemCount_;                 //lists how many items are currently in the list
};

int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList<int> dl;

    // CHANGE HERE
    bool ret = dl.inserts(4, 1);
    ret = ret && dl.inserts(5, 2);
    ret = ret && dl.inserts(6, 3);
    ret = ret && dl.inserts(7, 4);
    ret = ret && dl.inserts(8, 2);
    ret = ret && dl.inserts(9, 4);
    if (!ret) {
        std::cout << "Insert failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    dl.display();
}
```